# Hide cookies if button pressed and set to the session

Tags: javascript

I have a web site developed on Django with JS. I have a modal popup window that shows cookies information after the site was opened. This modal has two buttons. In JavaScrip I had function that hides the popup window and set `sessionStorage` attribute to true in order to hide modal window when accessing other pages on the website, while session is opened for user. It works, but modal still appears at the couple of mini seconds when the page reloaded. Either site is loading too slow or I made a mistake. What is wrong?

```
let accept_btn = document.querySelector('#accept_id');
let decline_btn = document.querySelector('#decline_id');
let modal = document.querySelector('.cookie__banner');

function checkedCookies() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('modalClosed')) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
 }

 checkedCookies();  

 function hideModal() {
    modal.style.opacity = '0';
    modal.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    setTimeout(() => {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }, 500);
    sessionStorage.setItem('modalClosed', 'true');
 }

accept_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideModal();
});

decline_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hideModal();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

# some code here

}
```

Comment: You need to do the opposite. Hide the modal standard and SHOW the modal if you need to